# Iterating through list of class in Dart

Tags: dart

```
class product {
  String name;
  String price;
  String quantity;
  product({this.name, this.price, this.quantity});
}

void main() {
  List<product> listofProducts = [
    product(name: "A", price: "10"),
    product(name: "B", price: "10"),
    product(name: "C", price: "10"),
    product(name: "D", price: "10"),
    product(name: "E", price: "10"),
    product(name: "F", price: "10")
  ];
  print(listofProducts.indexOf(product(name: "B", price: "10")));
}
```

How do I find the index of the product(name: "B", price: "10") in listofProducts list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use indexOf in List of Map in DART](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58956044/cant-use-indexof-in-list-of-map-in-dart)

Answer (score 2):

since the items of your list are not primitve, they are reference types , you need to use the `indexWhere` method on the list

```
final index = listofProducts.indexWhere((product) => product.name == "B" && product.price == "10");

print(index)
```

this way you iterate over each element of the array of products and find the index of that item. becuase you are having reference types as items.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative you can override `==` and `hashCode` so you change what Dart understands as equal of `Product` objects (default behavior is that objects are only equal if they are the same instance in memory).

By doing the following we change it so two `Product` objects are equal if they have the same name, price and quantity values.

```
import 'package:quiver/core.dart';

class Product {
  String name;
  String price;
  String quantity;
  Product({this.name, this.price, this.quantity});

  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    if (other is Product) {
      return other.name == name &&
          other.price == price &&
          other.quantity == quantity;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => hash3(name, price, quantity);
}

void main() {
  List<Product> listofProducts = [
    Product(name: "A", price: "10"),
    Product(name: "B", price: "10"),
    Product(name: "C", price: "10"),
    Product(name: "D", price: "10"),
    Product(name: "E", price: "10"),
    Product(name: "F", price: "10")
  ];
  print(listofProducts.indexOf(Product(name: "B", price: "10"))); // 1
}
```

To implement the `hashCode` I can recommend use the [quiver](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver) package which has the [hash3](https://pub.dev/documentation/quiver/latest/quiver.core/hash3.html) method to make it more convenient to combine the hash of 3 values.